# styles-m.css 404 (Not Found) after installing ElasticSuite Module by Smile. | Elasticsearch

Tags: magento2, 404, elasticsearch

After installation of this module: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/ the front-end is now messed up. Installed using composer. **Magento ver. 2.2.4** with **ElasticSuite 2.6.x latest release**.

In the console I get:

> GET http://www.example.co.uk/static/version1540202793/frontend/Venustheme/body_fitness_child/en_GB/css/styles-m.css 404 (Not Found)

I cleared the cache and even deployed static content again, however, the error is still present.

Anyone have experience or is using this module? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution...

I had no error logs because for some reason file permissions of var/log changed. Fixing the permissions gave me an exception of undeclared variables in `_module.less`.

Declaring the variables in the `.less` file fixed the problem.